# I can see my images with gatsby develop, but not on production site

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, gatsby, cdn, gatsby-image

I have my site's images stored in the `src/images` folder in my Gatsby project. I reference those files in `<StaticImage>` components after importing them from the images folder, like so:

Within `index.js`:

```
import myImage from '../images/flag.jpeg'
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
```

and later inside the same file:

```
      <StaticImage className="flag" src={myImage} alt="flag"/>
```

I can see this image and others just fine when running the site locally (`gatsby develop`), but when I deploy the site to AWS activate, I do not see ANY images.

What could be going wrong? Could this be a React issue?

Also, I cannot see videos either, though I am not aware of a `<StaticVideo/>` component

Comment: Does it work building locally? Have you tried directly: `<StaticImage className="flag" src="../images/flag.jpeg" alt="flag"/>`

Comment: I just tried that, but it still doesn't work in production. Blocks appear where the images should be.

Comment: What about using absolute paths?

Comment: any solution for this?